# ps2pdf -dEPSCrop input.eps cannot crop input with \pagecolor{<non-white>}

Tags: pdf, conversion, eps, crop, ps2pdf

If I set `\pagecolor{}` to any color other than `white`, I will get a strange result.

```
rem batch.bat takes a file name without extension.
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %1
dvips -E %1 -o %1-temp.eps
epstool --copy --bbox %1-temp.eps %1.eps
ps2pdf -dEPSCrop %1.eps
```

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pagecolor{red}% please try white or disable it.
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](2,2)
\psframe(2,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it  a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not a bug in `ps2pdf`.

`ps2pdf -dEPSCrop` takes the boundingbox from the eps file. Here, `epstool` has put a very large bounding box in the file. `epstool --copy --bbox` uses the ghostscript bbox device to calculate the bounding box, and you already know that this has a problem in recent versions of ghostscript when there is a coloured background (whether you want to call this a "bug" in ghostscript is debatable).